# new instance of wso2 api manager 3.2.0 connect to existing oracle database

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I had two working node of wso2 api manager 3.2.0 version(load balanced ).I forced to delete one node and reinstall it, now my issue is the new instance doesn't read existing data from oracle database(carbon_db ,wso2am_db,wso2_shared.db) and no api published in new instance,how to solve it and what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following config to the **<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml** to reindexed the API data in the database. Then restart the server. This might resolve your issue.

```
[indexing] 
enable = true 
re_indexing = 1
```